# How can I allow the access to my computer via Google Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am trying to allow the access to my computer via Google Chrome Remote Desktop. I see that my device (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate) is off-line:

[image]

I am trying  to configure it but don't see any option to make it online:

[image]

I have installed the Google Chrome Remote Desktop Chrome App:

[image]

How can I allow the access to my computer via Google Chrome Remote Desktop?

Comment: Have you opened and forwarded traffic to the device on port 443?

Comment: @Ramhound no, I don't believe it's compulsory though

Comment: My research says otherwise, I would try forwarding the port, especially since the device appears offline.